# shapefile to sde and vice versa

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase

I have an ArcMap 10.3.1 basic License and therefore cannot export data to SDE's connections.  Is there an open source tool that I can use to export shapefiles to an sde?  I have found [shp2sde](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/datamgmt/shp2sde.htm) and [sde2shp](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/datamgmt/sde2shp.htm) but these tool are outdated because of this statement in the documentation:

> Note: This function is not supported on 64-bit Windows, Linux, or HP-Itanium.

I'm using Windows.

If there is not a tool do I have any alternative other than upgrading to Advanced?

Is there anyway to do this without upgrading my existing license.  i.e some light weight opensource tool

Comment: Those tools are outdated because they were deprecated at 10.2 and not released at 10.3. The unsupported tools were the coverage translators (cov2sde /sde2cov) because Workstation was never released on those platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could upgrade to a Standard level license to achieve this.

There is no need for an Advanced level license to write to ArcSDE, although it can.

Comment: So there is no alternative other than upgrade?

Comment: The only way I know is to upgrade but I am not an ArcSDE specialist.